# Output Common Elements of Two Lists using Sets

Tags: python, list, element

I'd like to write a function definition that takes two lists and returns a single set with the values that each list has in common.

Formally, here are some assertions I'd like to pass:

```
assert get_values_in_common([5, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 5]) == {3, 5}
assert get_values_in_common([1, 2], [2, 2, 3]) == {2}
assert get_values_in_common(["tomato", "mango", "kiwi"], ["eggplant", "tomato", "broccoli"]) == {"tomato"}
```

Here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
def get_values_in_common(x, y):
    list = ""
    for a in x:
        if a in x and a in y:
            list.append(a)
    return list
```

I receive an error output that I know has to do with strings and integers, but am unsure what exactly the problem is. (Maybe it's that I make the above list by saying `list = ""`?):

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Always add language in question tags, otherwise you can get wrong answers.

Comment: you have to use list - `list = []` - to append elements. For string you can only use `+` like `"" + str(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `append()` then you have to use list

```
 list = []
```

If you use string `list = ""` then you can only concatenate strings

```
 list = list + str(a)
```

But you need `set` as answer then you should use `list = set()` and `add(a)`

```
def get_values_in_common(x, y):
    result = set()

    for a in x:
        if a in y: # there is no need to check `if a in x`
            result.add(a)

    return result
```

But you can do the same shorter

```
def get_values_in_common(x, y):
    return set(x) & set(y)
```

And this is why `set()` can be very useful.